# Linux: How is the input latency of a Wacom tablet distributed among the various software- and hardware components?

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, tablet, latency, wacom

Say I have the following setup:

- Linux Kernel
- [input-wacom](https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom) kernel driver
- [xf86-input-wacom](https://github.com/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom) X11 driver
- Wacom tablet

How is input latency distributed among these various components? Are there any bottlenecks? If one wanted to make software patches to reduce latency (even by a couple of milliseconds), which parts of the "pipeline" should one look at first?

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @jsotola There is no _problem_ I'm trying to solve; I'm mostly just curious. If, however, there is some software bottleneck when it comes to graphics tablet latency that could be solved by improving the software, I'd like to take a stab at it. I use my graphics tablet to play a video game called Osu!, where even a latency reduction in the millisecond range can make a difference.